# What are hybrid-integer?

Tags: math, integer-arithmetic

what are Hybrid Integers mentioned in this problem and what are applications of Hybrid Integers?

[image: Hybrid Integers]

Comment: Your question belongs on a different forum, not StackOverflow, which deals with programming questions only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"what are Hybrid Integers?" They are defined in the first line of the problem description.

"what are applications of Hybrid Integers?"
They serve describing a programming challenge, which you have found.

Comment: Or maybe a math challenge.... in which case, admittedly, the whole Q/A is off-topic here....